# foreach table display error with <td>

Tags: php, symfony, for-loop, foreach, doctrine

Pls what am I doing wrong?

I have an array ($result) having some keys and values in it obtained via doctrine_mongodb and I am trying to display the results in a table using php in different cells.

```
    foreach ($result as $docrow)
    {
        echo "<tr height=\"20\" class=\"evenListRowS1\">";
           **echo "<td>"$docrow->getName()"</td>";**
           echo "<td>1</td>";
           echo "<td>2</td>";
```

Seems like the issue is with the "" (exclamation marks) when I use . Error message i get is:
Parse: syntax error, unexpected '$docrow' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dot(.) to concat echo try this

```
foreach ($result as $docrow)
        {
            echo "<tr height=\"20\" class=\"evenListRowS1\">";
               echo "<td>".$docrow->getName()."</td>";
               echo "<td>1</td>";
               echo "<td>2</td>";
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas, you got it right. I appreciate... Please how do I know when to use dot(.) to concat echo? any time I expect a string value?

Comment: You are supposed to use " for adding string values and . to concat  them, and variables should not have ".You should add HTML tags like   "<tag>" this Read this manual http://in3.php.net/echo.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, You have missed to add `.` concat the variable between the strings.

```
 echo "<td>".$docrow->getName()."</td>"; 
       .....^
```

instead of

```
 echo "<td>"$docrow->getName()"</td>";
```

Now your code should be,

```
     foreach ($result as $docrow)
     {
        echo "<tr height=\"20\" class=\"evenListRowS1\">";
        echo "<td>".$docrow->getName()."</td>";
        echo "<td>1</td>";
        echo "<td>2</td>";
     }
```

Comment: I'm really curious about it, BTW +1

Answer (score 1):

**1**. You missed **dot** before and after `$docrow->getName()`

Try :

```
echo "<td>".$docrow->getName()."</td>";
```

Or :

```
echo "<td>{$docrow->getName()}</td>";
```

Read this for more info : [**String operators**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

---

**2** . And you missed a bracket after your loop :

```
foreach ($result as $docrow)
        {
            echo "<tr height=\"20\" class=\"evenListRowS1\">";
               echo "<td>"$docrow->getName()"</td>";
               echo "<td>1</td>";
               echo "<td>2</td>";
        }  // <-- you missed this
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<td>$docrow->getName()</td>";
```

You don't need to unquote to use a variable if using double quotes.

If you left your code the way it was, you would either need to a) put a comma after the "" and one after $docrow->getName(), or b) concatenate the variable into the string.

Comment: Better to escape with `echo "<td>{$docrow->getName()}</td>";`

Comment: Curiosity: why is this better?

Comment: Hm, maybe because many IDE begin to highlight syntax in `{}`, and it more accurate programming? ;)

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm self taught, so I'm partially here to locate my misconceptions.  :)